# Continue main while loop from within nested while loop in Python3.7

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

i decided to make a blackjack game, i have it finished, the only problem im having is that sometimes when you choose to play again, the program uses the same value for the variables. I'm pretty sure ive isolated the problem to the nested `while` loops, my code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/9zr9qCU6 ive tried to make the `resetGame()` function to return empty list objects for both `dealer_hand` and `player_hand` but that didnt fix it either, is there a way to continue the main `while` loop from within these nested `while` loops? or would i have to refactor each nested `while` loop into a separate function?

code:

```
# Blackjack
import random
from card_deck import Deck
from time import sleep
from sys import exit

d = Deck()
deck_of_cards = d.deck_return()
print('*' * 30)
print('*  Welcome to BlackJack!  *')
print('*    Made by: p0seidon    *')
print('*' * 30)


def shuffleDeck(deck):
    random.shuffle(deck)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck


def dealCard(shuffled_deck):
    return random.sample(shuffled_deck, k=2)


def removeFromDeck(hand1, hand2):
    global deck_of_cards
    for x in hand1:
        deck_of_cards.remove(x)

    for x in hand2:
        deck_of_cards.remove(x)


def hit(deck_to_hit):
    return random.choice(deck_to_hit)


def endGame():
    print('Thanks for playing!\n'
          'Better luck next time!')
    sleep(3)
    exit()


def restartGame():
    restart = ''
    restart_list = ['y', 'n']
    while restart not in restart_list:
        restart = input('Would you like to play again? [y/n]: ')

    return restart


def resetGame():
    global deck_of_cards
    print('Loading new deck.\n'
          'Please wait...')
    sleep(3)
    deck_of_cards = d.deck_return()
    return deck_of_cards


play_again = 'y'
while play_again == 'y':
    # shuffles and deals 2 cards to dealer and player
    ready_deck = shuffleDeck(deck_of_cards)
    dealer_hand = dealCard(ready_deck)
    player_hand = dealCard(ready_deck)

    # removes the cards in players hand from the deck, making the game a little more life-like
    removeFromDeck(dealer_hand, player_hand)

    # checks to see if dealer won in the first hand
    if sum(dealer_hand) == 21:
        print('Dealer\'s first hand is', dealer_hand, 'totaling 21.\n'
                                                      'You lose!')
        play_again = restartGame()
        if play_again == 'y':
            deck_of_cards = resetGame()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            endGame()

    # check to see if player won or busted in the first hand
    if sum(player_hand) == 21:
        print('You win with the initial hand of', player_hand, '\n'
                                                               'CONGRATULATIONS!')
        play_again = restartGame()
        if play_again == 'y':
            deck_of_cards = resetGame()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            endGame()
    elif sum(player_hand) > 21:
        print('Looks like you busted in your first hand consisting of', player_hand, '\n'
                                                                                     'Better luck next time!')
        play_again = restartGame()
        if play_again == 'y':
            deck_of_cards = resetGame()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            endGame()

    # shows only one of the dealers card at random and shows the player his hand
    print('DEBUG: dealers hand:', dealer_hand)
    # print('Dealer has', dealer_hand[random.randint(0, 1)], 'the other card is hidden')
    print('You have', player_hand)

    # sums the cards in players hand and dealers hand
    player_sum = sum(player_hand)
    dealer_sum = sum(dealer_hand)

    # player logic
    while player_sum < 21:
        choice = input('Would you like to hit or stay (h/s)?: ')
        if choice == 'h':
            new_player_card = hit(ready_deck)
            player_hand.append(new_player_card)
            print('Current hand:', player_hand)
            player_sum += new_player_card
            if player_sum == 21:  # player wins on hit
                print('You win!\n'
                      'Winning hand:', player_hand)
                play_again = restartGame()
                if play_again == 'y':
                    deck_of_cards = resetGame()
                elif play_again == 'n':
                    endGame()
            elif player_sum > 21:  # player busts on hit
                print('looks like you went overboard. Your final hand was:', player_hand)
                play_again = restartGame()
                if play_again == 'y':
                    deck_of_cards = resetGame()
                    continue
                elif play_again == 'n':
                    endGame()
        elif choice == 's':
            print('You locked in at', player_sum)
            sleep(2)
            break

    # dealer logic
    while dealer_sum < 17:
        print('Dealers hand:', dealer_hand)
        print('Dealer hits..')
        sleep(1)
        new_dealer_card = hit(ready_deck)
        dealer_hand.append(new_dealer_card)
        sleep(0.5)
        dealer_sum += new_dealer_card
        if dealer_sum > 21:  # dealer busts on hit
            print('Dealer has busted!\n'
                  'You Win!')
            print('Dealers losing hand:', dealer_hand)
            play_again = restartGame()
            if play_again == 'y':
                deck_of_cards = resetGame()
                continue
            elif play_again == 'n':
                endGame()
        elif 17 < dealer_sum <= 21:  # dealer stays
            print('Dealers hand:', dealer_hand)
            print('Dealer stays..')
            sleep(1)
            break

    # compares player sum with dealer sum to determine who won
    if player_sum > dealer_sum:
        print('You win!\n'
              'Your winning hand:', player_hand, '\n'
                                                 'Dealers losing hand:', dealer_hand)
        play_again = restartGame()
        if play_again == 'y':
            deck_of_cards = resetGame()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            endGame()
    elif dealer_sum > player_sum:
        print('Looks like you were unlucky this time...Dealer won..\n'
              'Dealer winning hand:', dealer_hand)
        play_again = restartGame()
        if play_again == 'y':
            deck_of_cards = resetGame()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            endGame()
    elif player_hand == dealer_hand:
        print('Its a tie!')
        sleep(0.5)
        print('Your hand:', player_hand)
        sleep(0.5)
        print('Dealers hand:', dealer_hand)
        sleep(0.5)
        play_again = resetGame()
        if play_again == 'y':
            deck_of_cards = resetGame()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            endGame()
`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the actual source code in the post - if the link dies, the question becomes useless.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**is there a way to continue the main while loop from within these nested while loops?**

No. See the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html), `continue` always contine the innermost loop.

**would i have to refactor each nested while loop into a separate function?**

Yes. That's better. I am tired at reading your code because it is too long to understand quickly. A better pattern to your problem would be this:

```
def play():
    while your_condition:
        while another_condition:
            pass # do something
            yesno = input("yes or no?")
            if yesno == "y":
                return True

terminate = False
while not terminate:
    terminate = play()
```

By using `return`, you find a way to `break` or `continue` an outer loop from an inner loop.